# Flexslsider direction nav between image and caption of slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexslider

I' got a layout for a slideshow that shows captions above of images. I would like to show the direction nav between caption and images as you can see on the screenshot.
Can not get it to work ([see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wp4bt434/5/)) - I think it is because the nav is inside the markup of the slides itself. Can someone show me how I can accomplish this layout?

[image]

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="main-slider" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <figcaption>
          <h1>Ausstellungsansicht</h1>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
        </figcaption>
        <div class="slideshow-controls">
        </div>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figcaption>
          <h1>Test</h1>
          <p>
            UV-Druck auf Pappwabenplatte, Edelstahl
            <br /> Unikat, Zertifikat
          </p>
        </figcaption>
        <div class="slideshow-controls">

        </div>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
        </figure>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ready event of slider you can force css for  tag with property margin-top: 30 or 40px;

and provide top to the next and prev arrows by using their class names. top:50px;

Comment: I would be glad if you could edit the fiddle since I am not that tech savvy.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wp4bt434/7/ Also download and add arrow images to sliders directory structure (You can get structure on flexslider)